# Javascript Functions and Objects Confusion

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, we have two fundamental building blocks called functions and objects. But I'm a bit confused about the phrase **functions are special type of objects**. Anyways, in Javascript:

We create functions like this:

```
function foo(){}
```

Now the above declared function also behaves like an object as below:

```
foo.staticMethod = function(){}
```

Ok. I understand it.

Now similarly we create objects like this:

```
var obj = new Object() // Not using object literal here
```

That means, we need a function constructor `Object` to make even an empty object.

**But Functions are also objects. How????**

So my simple question is, if `Object` is used to create any new object, then how it can be an object itself as it accepts a property `Object.prototype` or I should say how a function can be an object ?

Comment: Well javascript isnt written in javascript...

Comment: May be its not but how an object constructor itself can be an object?

Comment: No, you *don't* need a constructor to create an object. Function, object, array or regex literal syntax do it without.

Comment: @Bergi But I read somewhere that the literals are also wrapped by the constructor internally. Is it true?

Comment: @ManishJangir Not really. Maybe the other way round. In reality, they just both use the low-level builtin primitive that creates an object value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Object(){
  return {};
}
```